# Display business address when accepting manage pages permission

Tags: php, facebook

The dialog window that appears after accepting permissions for our application that displays the FB page the user wants to allow access for does not display the business address.

Why is this an issue? The customer is unable to choose the correct location and they often have admin rights on many locations of their business which have the exact same name.

What type of solution am I looking for? A way to extend permissions to display the address of the FB page when connecting. We already have manage and publish pages permissions approved with our app.

I have searched SO and FB developer threads without any luck.

Comment: please improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How so? This isn't a matter of displaying any code. I already have an approved fb application that does what it's supposed to.

Comment: You could add screenshots. And add which solutions you have tried yourself, and where you searched for answers. Also, the first sentence is difficult to understand since it is too long.

Comment: It is impossible for you to change anything about how the login dialog behaves. If you need something like this, then you can only have your users grant your app access to _all_ their pages, and then make API requests to get more details about those pages afterwards. Build a list from that to let them chose with page the actually want to perform actions up.

Comment: That's a good idea @misorude. A lot of work, but a possible work around.